# embed html5 youtube video in a lightbox (using fancybox)

Tags: html, video, youtube, fancybox, lightbox

I've already embedded the video inside a lightbox and everthing works well right now. If I turn off my adobe flash player plugin I get an error. I want it to switch to html5 player (like it does if I embed the video in an iframe).

Is there a known solution?

Comment: It's version 1.3.4
edit: thanks for your help you put me into the right direction :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use Fancybox2. It automatically switches to the HTML5 player if flash player is deativated or not installed.